# Loading third-party DLL in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have two questions.

Question1:

How can we add a reference to a third-party DLL (like recaptcha) in a website/web app from a folder. The folder can be present anywhere like in the C: drive or inside the website/webapp's root directory.

Question2:

Is it possible to add a reference to a third-party DLL in a website/webapp by using app/web.config? I know it can be done if the DLL is added to GAC. Other than this method, is there is any there way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question:

You can add it from within the project, open VS2010, in solution explorer under your projects 'references' folder, right click -> Add Reference -> Find the dll.

Then you just have to reference it from within your code. For example I use a telerik library and I refer to in via:

Front end:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
```

Code:

```
using Telerik.Web.UI;
```

Comment: For your second question, I don't think it is possible but it may be. I wouldn't think so because the compiler needs to have everything together to compile, but there may be a way to tell it, 'Hey grab this too' from the config. But I have never had to do that so I'm not sure